# vuejs : how to set link to popover block in for circle

Tags: vuejs2

In my laravel5.5/vuejs2.5 application I need to show list of buttons with popover text using vue-js-popover ( https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-popover ) library
But I failed the valid syntax. I tried as :

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="popoverData, index in popoverDataArray">
        <button :v-popover="'hint_'+popoverData.id">Toggle popover # {{ popoverData.id }}</button>

        <popover :name="'hint_'+popoverData.id">
            {{ popoverData.text }}
        </popover>

    </li>
</ul>

...


data: function () {
    return {
        ...
        popoverDataArray:[
            {id: 1, text : 'Lorem  ipsum dolor sit amet, 1111' },
            {id: 2, text : 'Lorem  ipsum dolor sit amet, 2222.' },
            ...
        ],

}
```

Which is the correct syntax in button definition to set link to popover block ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also show your console error?

Comment: There is no console error, but it does not work

Comment: Looks like you're using shorthand directive syntax at `:v-popover=` should that be.. `v-popover=` or possibly `:popover=`

Comment: I changed the code in start topic under EDIT mark : it has no error in console, but not any popover visible...